# Hive Adding JAR Not Working

Tags: hive

I am trying to import a file that has the fields quoted. I found out about the csv-serde JAR and have attempted to use this to minimal success.

I downloaded the JAR from:
https://github.com/ogrodnek/csv-serde

I added to my HDFS system in the /tmp directory.

When I try to use the View to HIVE from within Ambari I set the following:

```
ADD JAR /tmp/csv-serde-1.1.2-0.11.0-all.jar;
```

This throws an error that the file does not exist:

> H110 Unable to submit statement. Error while processing statement:
>   /tmp/csv-serde-1.1.2-0.11.0-all.jar does not exist [ERROR_STATUS]

I then try from terminal calling hive:

> hive> ADD JAR /tmp/csv-serde-1.1.2-0.11.0-all.jar;

This succeeds. I then create my EXTERNAL TABLE and then select some fields to make sure it is good from within the CLI hive environment and all works.

I then go back to the Hive View from within Ambari and when I run any type of operation on the table I get:

> H110 Unable to submit statement. Error while compiling statement:
>   FAILED: RuntimeException
>   MetaException(message:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Class
>   com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde not found) [ERROR_STATUS]

When I try to query this from MS SQL via the ODBC drive I also get the same error.

I have looked at multiple posts on this forum about adding so and so .jar and this and that to:

> /usr/lib/hive

That directory does not exit on my cluster either in the base OS level or in the HDFS file system. Where exactly, and how, should I put the .jar file such that I can query my tables outside of the hive CLI?

Answer (score 1):

For those facing a similar issue, I managed to resolve it today.

**My Problem:**
When trying to use the following syntax in Hive:

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  "separatoeChar" = ",",
  "quoteChar" = "\""
)
```

Hive didn't recognize org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde.

**Solution:**

I downloaded the JAR file from this repository: https://github.com/adatao/mvnrepos/blob/master/releases/com/bizo/csv-serde/1.1.2-0.11.0/csv-serde-1.1.2-0.11.0-all.jar

Note: Download the JAR file to any location, and remember its path.

In the Hive terminal, run the following command:

```
hive> ADD JAR "path_to_your_downloaded_jar/csv-serde-1.1.2-0.11.0-all.jar";
```

Replace "path_to_your_downloaded_jar" with the actual path where you saved the JAR file.

Replace the previous Hive code with the following:

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  "separatoeChar" = ",",
  "quoteChar" = "\""
)
```

This should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the jar somewhere in HDFS.  Many people use /tmp in HDFS as you did with your local FS.  For example:

```
hdfs dfs -put /tmp/csv-serde-1.1.2-0.11.0-all.jar /tmp
```

Then when you are in Hive View you would

```
ADD JAR hdfs://$HOSTNAME:$PORTNUM/tmp/csv-serde-1.1.2-0.11.0-all.jar;
```

This should work and allow you to query your data.

Answer (score 0):

Try the full path, e.g:

```
ADD JAR hdfs://<host>/<port>/tmp/csv-serde-1.1.2-0.11.0-all.jar;
```

If for some reason the configuration that is in play from within the Ambari viewer is different and default FS isn't defined, then this could work.

The other option you mention - I believe it doesn't matter which directory you put the jar in as long as it's on the same host where the hive server runs, and hive-site.xml points to it. Pick any location on the file system (e.g, /home/myname/jars) Edit hive-site.xml on the hive server machine

```
<property>
  <name>hive.aux.jars.path</name>
  <value>/home/myname/jars</value>
</property>
```

and copy csv-serde-1.1.2-0.11.0-all.jar to /home/myname/jars (on local fs, not on hdfs). Restart hive and try. In this method you don't need to use ADD JAR at all - the jar will be included the hive server class path automatically.

Another option which I read about but never tried is to place the jar in the hive lib directory. You can try that too, but make sure to restart hive first.

Note about ADD JAR: The ADD JAR command and the query that uses it later on must be executed within the same session. Commands from within Hive CLI are in a single session, so it works. I don't know how Ambari Hive view manages sessions.

Answer (score 0):

example if jar exist in HDFS:

```
hive>add jar hdfs:///tmp/csv-serde-1.1.2-0.11.0-all.jar;
```

did return

```
converting to local hdfs:///tmp/csv-serde-1.1.2-0.11.0-all.jar
Added [/tmp/d6528831-4f3c-41e4-a4cf-121a63796a0f_resources/csv-serde-1.1.2-0.11.0-all.jar] to class path
Added resources: [hdfs:///tmp/csv-serde-1.1.2-0.11.0-all.jar]
```

example if jar exist in local filesystem

```
hive>add jar file:///tmp/csv-serde-1.1.2-0.11.0-all.jar;
```

...